# What is the priority of eventListener callback functions in the event loop?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

```js
console.log("11111");

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("22222");
}, 5000);

Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  console.log("33333");
});

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("44444 +");
});

// 10 sec sync delay. This gives me enough time to stack them into appropriate Queues.
const syncWait = (ms) => {
  const end = Date.now() + ms;
  while (Date.now() < end) continue;
};
syncWait(10000);

console.log("55555");
```

Output:

```
11111
55555
33333
44444 +
22222
```

What is the exact priority of callback functions triggered using `addEventListener` compared to microtask and macrotask queue callbacks in the Event Loop? In other words, during which exact phase of the Event Loop are they dequeued from their respective queues?

Comment: Not sure what "*This gives me enough time to stack them into appropriate Queues.*" is meant to achieve, can you explain?

Comment: User-triggered events are macro tasks, but whether a browser is going to handle timeouts or clicks with higher priority is left open to the implementation. Their goal is to provide a good responsive user experience, and adjust their scheduling according to it.

Comment: When the code starts executing, it first runs synchronous code and registers callback functions. The part that you mentioned comes after synchronous callback registrations, which keeps the synchronous part running and prevents the event loop from taking action. During this time, I trigger the click event, time expires etc, all callbacks get queued (microtasks, macrotasks). At the end of the 10 seconds, the event loop comes into the picture and starts pushing callbacks onto the Call Stack. So, I can clearly see which ones have priority because they were all there when the Event Loop starts.

Comment: @Bergi yea, that makes sense. So, the answer is the classic: "it depends" because of JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EventListener` callbacks are called synchronously. There is no priority for them. They may be called in **any** *phase* of the event loop.

*Wait, what?*

Yes, it may seem like hair splitting, but what is queued are [tasks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#concept-task), not the event callbacks. You can even trigger these callbacks yourself synchronously:

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("click callback");
});

console.log("before");
document.getElementById("test").dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
console.log("after");
```

```html
<button id=test>test</button>
```

This does matter, because whether your JS callback has been passed to the API, or attached to the `EventListener`, has no incidence at all with regards to the priority system.

To understand the task priority system, we have to look at [how the event loop is defined in HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:event-loop).

And particularly, we'll be interested in its second operation, which is to pick a task from one of the possibly various *task-queues*, and execute it. Note that the specs don't really ask that there are multiple *task queues*, but they ask that there are multiple [*task sources*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-source), so that we can be sure that the tasks queued in a given *task source* are all executed in order. But modern browsers do indeed have multiple *task queues*. How they create these is a bit complex with a lot of edge cases, but the basic observable setup is that they'll map the specs *task sources* to *task queues*.
So in this step, they are allowed to pick a task from whatever *task source* they see fit, and that's where the prioritization system is done.

This means that **only the tasks that have been queued to a *task queue* can be part of the prioritization system**, so for instance, rendering frame callbacks (queued through `requestAnimationFrame`), or `scroll` and `resize` event handlers, etc. aren't part of this prioritization system. These are to be called in the special [*update the rendering*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) phase of the event loop, which is entered only once in a while (generally when the monitor sent its VSync signal).
Microtasks are yet another beast and they are even less part of the prioritization system. The [microtask queue](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#microtask-queue) is to be visited every time a script or a callback [ends its execution](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script), (if there is nothing on the JS stack anymore). There is no way that any other task slips in between, so there is no prioritization system in here.

Now if we come back to your example, we're left with the task that will be queued by `setTimeout`, and the one that will be queued by the user interaction (UI).

As we said before, the specs don't define the prioritization, and the browsers will use their own heuristics to set it. And they may even use a starvation protection system, so that one task queue doesn't block all the queues indefinitely. But what is observed for years in almost all browsers is that UI events (which will trigger your click handler callback) have an higher priority than timer (or even network) tasks. But since there is nothing defined, you shouldn't rely on this behavior, and more importantly, **it shouldn't matter to you** as a web-dev.

Note that we should soon be given the ability to control the priority of some task we'll queue thanks to the [Prioritized Task Scheduling API](https://wicg.github.io/scheduling-apis/), (already available in Chromium browsers), which does expose three levels of prioritization: *user-blocking* (which roughly corresponds to UI events today), *user-visible* (basically timers and networks), and *background* (idle tasks). Maybe, when all this will be incorporated in HTML will all the different *task sources* have their own priority defined, maybe.

Comment: It is crystal clear now. o7