# is dom event handler a microtask or a macrotask in the event loop?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-loop

=== update on Aug 18th, 2023

`.click()` is synchronous

(I've made a mistake in my previous code snippet,

the callback in the `Promise` constructor also runs *synchronously*)

if I add one line of `Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('then'))`, everything make sense!)

===
I've read lots of articles about event loop, but seems a few of them mentioned that is a DOM event handler a micro or a macro task?

and I was trying to figure it out by code, but something weird happened.

```js
document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click btn2')
})

document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click btn1')
  setTimeout(() => console.log('timer'));
  new Promise(res => { console.log('promise');res(); });
  document.querySelector('#btn2').click();
})
```

```html
<button id="btn1">btn1</button>
<button id="btn2">btn2</button>
```

in this snippet, the console output is

```
click btn1
promise
click btn2
timer
```

so it seems to tell DOM event handler is a microtask

but when I adjust the line order in the code, I move the `.click()` to the top

```js
document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click btn2')
})

document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#btn2').click();
  console.log('click btn1')
  setTimeout(() => console.log('timer'));
  new Promise(res => { console.log('promise');res(); });
})
```

```html
<button id="btn1">btn1</button>
<button id="btn2">btn2</button>
```

the output is:

```
click btn2
click btn1
promise
timer
```

the `click` event runs before the sync code?

can someone explain this to me, thanks

Comment: The browser does not have to guarantee that asynchronous code executes in the order you wrote them. Especially if you bring `setTimeout` and `Promise` into the mix. Those are executed asynchronously and your output in the console may be more incidental and less causational.

Comment: `click()` produced by a program is not actually the same as manual click.

Comment: Everything is synchronous in your code, except the timer. That's why outputs follow code-order, except the timer, that always comes last. You can go to `click()` on MDN, and then follow the specification https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click#specifications

Comment: Very relevant: [Is triggering event listeners using ".click()" synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33621545)

Comment: @PeterKrebs asynchronous execution does not mean "random order" `setTimeout() => console.log(1)); setTimeout() => console.log(2)); setTimeout() => console.log(3));` will always run asynchronously but would ***never*** produce a sequence other than 1 -> 2 -> 3. The execution of `setTimeout` and promise followups in particular are via macro/microtask queues which is also not quite random. As long as the async tasks take no real time, the results are predictable. However, there is largely no guarantee if they do take some time, e.g., AJAX requests, calls to database, etc.

Comment: @VLAZ almost a dupe, assuming the `Promise`-callback-runs-on-spot is known to OP.

Comment: Also relevant for "native" events: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76673558/what-is-the-priority-of-eventlistener-callback-functions-in-the-event-loop/